# Telegram Bot webhook really slow

Tags: bots, webhooks, telegram-bot

I've created a telegram bot and set a webhook as described in the docs. For testing purposes I've set it up so once you send the bot a message it replies back with the same message.

Now the issue I am having is that the updates from telegram are coming back really slowly and there are some messages I haven't received yet. Am I missing something or is the webhook method just really slow?

Comment: It's not slow. Check everything again.

Comment: Your webhook is probably slow. Put logs to time how long does it take to process requests from Telegram. The probability is higher that an issue is on your side.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Turns out I wasn't responding the telegram server after I got the POST request. Due to this, the server wasn't sure if I got the previous updates and was constantly sending my webhook past updates.

I have an express server and I added this bit of line after handling the POST Request.

```
res.sendStatus(403)
```

You can also confirm this by going to this url

```
https://api.telegram.org/<token>/getWebhookInfo
```

You'll see a property called **pending_update_count**. It should zero or close to it.

Comment: In my case, I returned the response via js Promise - and your answer made me think that perhaps Telegram API doesn't like it all so much, which turned out to be correct..

Comment: Why not send back status 200 though?